# ReactDOM passing a function with parameters to a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm programming in React for the first time and I have a problem which I don't understand how I can solve without change everything, but it feels like there must be a solution.

I have this code at the index.js

```
export var updateString = function (test3){
    var test1 = 'hello world1'
    //do something mother
}

ReactDOM.render(<Child triggerUpdateString={() => updateString ('hello world3')}/>, document.getElementById('child'));
```

And then I got the following code at child.js

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  handleString = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.triggerUpdateString('hello world2')
    //do something child }}
```

I do not have a problem to get 'hello world1' or 'hello world3' in the "do something mother" part but I cannot get the 'hello world2' string.

How do I get the string from the child up to the updateString function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling updateString always with "hello world3". thats the reason you are not seeing it. make your callback triggerUpdateString based on arguments. Something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Child triggerUpdateString={(str) => updateString (str)}/>, 
 document.getElementById('child'));
```

Then it should work for whatever you pass in as arguments.
Thanks Feedbacks are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here you're setting a local variable `test1` to a constant value, but the argument that you're passing (`test3`) is never used anywhere:

```
export var updateString = function (test3){
    var test1 = 'hello world1'
    //do something mother
}
```

I think you meant to do this, but without seeing your code I'll just assume you're using both values somewhere in reality:

```
export var updateString = function (test3){
    var test1 = test3;
    //do something mother
}
```

Since we're just testing here, lets change that to use `console.log` so we have a meaningful result in the example code:

```
export var updateString = function (test3){
    console.log(test3);
    //do something mother
}
```

Now, since we changed our `updateString` function we don't need to wrap it in extra function calls to pass it:

```
<Child triggerUpdateString={() => updateString ('hello world3')}/>
```

You can just do this:

```
<Child triggerUpdateString={updateString}/>
```

Because we're just calling it and passing a value anyway:

```
this.props.triggerUpdateString('hello world2')
```

I hope this working example helps you, let me know if I misunderstood anything:

```js
const updateString = function (newValue){
    console.log("new value:", newValue);
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleString = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.triggerUpdateString('hello world2');
  }
  render() {
      return (<button onClick={this.handleString}>Test</button>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Child triggerUpdateString={updateString} />, document.getElementById('child'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="child"></div>
```